# (Wordpress) images to Work's attachment but doesnt appear in slider

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slider

just going to sum it up:
this is how THE SLIDER should look like-> http://luiszuno.com/themes/wp-dokedoke/work/porttitor/ (original demo)
and when I add images from media to the work it goes to content and not the slider like this -> http://netsurf.ir/work/project-2 (website is in persian language)
work-slider:

```
<?php
    /*
    *
    * Retrieve and displays all images 
    *
    */ 

    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'attachment', 
        'numberposts' => -1, 
        'post_status' => null, 
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    ); 
    $attachments = get_posts($args);
?>

<div id="project-gallery"><!-- swipper -->
<div class="gallery-container">
    <div class="swiper-container clearfix">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper clearfix">


        <!-- Images  -->
        <?php if ($attachments) : ?>
            <?php
                foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) :
                    $this_image = aq_resize($attachment->guid, 672);
            ?>
                <div class="swiper-slide"> <img src="<?php echo $this_image ?>" alt="<?php echo $attachment->guid ?>"> </div>

            <?php endforeach ?>
        <?php endif ?>  
        <!-- ENDS images -->


        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<!-- ENDS swipper -->
```

my work text:

```
<a href="somewhere/03.jpg(cant post more than 2links)"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-41" src="http://netsurf.ir/wp-content/uploads/03.jpg" alt="03" width="672" height="400" /></a> <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-42" src="somewhere/04.jpg" alt="04" width="672" height="400" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the code for the entire file where you are trying to add this slider to? Looks like the code you have is correct, but where you put this code it what matters.

Answer (score 1):

original theme sample which slider works fine: http://luiszuno.com/themes/wp-dokedoke/work/porttitor/

```
    <!-- work-->
    <section class="page-section zigzag" >
        <div class="page-section-inner">
        <h1 class="heading">Porttitor</h1>
            <div class="subheading"><p>example paragraph [&hellip;]</p>
</div>
        </div>


<div id="project-gallery"><!-- swipper -->
<div class="gallery-container">
    <div class="swiper-container clearfix">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper clearfix">


        <!-- Images  -->
                                    <div class="swiper-slide"> <img src="somewhere/worke2.jpg" alt="somewhere/worke2.jpg"> </div>

                            <div class="swiper-slide"> <img src="somewhere/workf2.jpg" alt="work/workf2.jpg"> </div>


        <!-- ENDS images -->


        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<!-- ENDS swipper -->
```

and here is my website the same part which slider doesnt work: http://netsurf.ir/work/project-2

```
    <!-- work-->
    <section class="page-section zigzag" >
        <div class="page-section-inner">
        <h1 class="heading">Project 2</h1>
            <div class="subheading"></div>
        </div>


<div id="project-gallery"><!-- swipper -->
<div class="gallery-container">
    <div class="swiper-container clearfix">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper clearfix">


        <!-- Images  -->

        <!-- ENDS images -->


        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<!-- ENDS swipper -->
```

image section is empty, but in wordpress I added the images to the work via "Add Media"

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I still do not see all of the code on the page. I don't know how familiar you are with wordpress and things like this slider, but here is what I see:

The code you have showed here looks correct. The only thing is, try copying all the styles from the live slider divs into the new one.

```
<div class="swiper-wrapper clearfix" style="width: 2688px; transform: translate3d(-1204px, 0px, 0px); -webkit-transform: translate3d(-1204px, 0px, 0px); transition: 0s; -webkit-transition: 0s; height: 400px;"><div class="swiper-slide" style="width: 672px; height: 400px;"> <img src="http://luiszuno.com/themes/wp-dokedoke/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/workf2.jpg" alt="http://luiszuno.com/themes/wp-dokedoke/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/workf2.jpg"> </div>

    <!-- Images  -->

        <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-visible swiper-slide-active" style="width: 672px; height: 400px;"> <img src="http://luiszuno.com/themes/wp-dokedoke/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/worke2.jpg" alt="http://luiszuno.com/themes/wp-dokedoke/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/worke2.jpg"> </div>

        <div class="swiper-slide" style="width: 672px; height: 400px;"> <img src="http://luiszuno.com/themes/wp-dokedoke/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/workf2.jpg" alt="http://luiszuno.com/themes/wp-dokedoke/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/workf2.jpg"> </div>

    <!-- ENDS images -->

    <div class="swiper-slide" style="width: 672px; height: 400px;"> <img src="http://luiszuno.com/themes/wp-dokedoke/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/worke2.jpg" alt="http://luiszuno.com/themes/wp-dokedoke/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/worke2.jpg"> </div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US" > <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Project 2 | Mr. imager </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netsurf.ir/wp-content/themes/dokedoke/css/initializr.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netsurf.ir/wp-content/themes/dokedoke/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netsurf.ir/wp-content/themes/dokedoke/css/idangerous.swiper.css">


            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netsurf.ir/wp-content/themes/dokedoke/css/responsive.css">

    <!-- FONTS -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <script src="http://netsurf.ir/wp-content/themes/dokedoke/js/modernizr.min.js"></script>

    <meta name='robots' content='noindex,follow' />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Mr. imager &raquo; Feed" href="http://netsurf.ir/feed" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Mr. imager &raquo; Comments Feed" href="http://netsurf.ir/comments/feed" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Mr. imager &raquo; Project 2 Comments Feed" href="http://netsurf.ir/work/project-2/feed" />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='contact-form-7-css'  href='http://netsurf.ir/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles.css?ver=4.0.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://netsurf.ir/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://netsurf.ir/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://netsurf.ir/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://netsurf.ir/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 
<link rel='prev' title='Project' href='http://netsurf.ir/work/project' />
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 4.0" />
<link rel='canonical' href='http://netsurf.ir/work/project-2' />
<link rel='shortlink' href='http://netsurf.ir/?p=54' />
</head>
<body class="single single-work postid-54 logged-in">

    <header>
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="menu-menu-1-container"><ul id="main-nav" class="sf-menu"><li id="menu-item-37" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-37"><a href="http://netsurf.ir/"><span>خانه</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-53" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-53"><a href="http://netsurf.ir/work"><span>نمونه کار</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-13" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-13"><a href="http://netsurf.ir/%d8%b3%d9%81%d8%a7%d8%b1%d8%b4-%d8%b7%d8%b1%d8%a7%d8%ad%db%8c"><span>سفارش طراحی</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-49" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-49"><a href="http://netsurf.ir/%d9%be%d8%b1%d8%af%d8%a7%d8%ae%d8%aa"><span>پرداخت</span></a></li>
</ul></div> </div>
</header>


    <!-- main content -->
    <div class="main">


        <div  id="page-title" class="main-title">
        <img src="http://netsurf.ir/wp-content/themes/dokedoke/img/logo.png"  alt="Mr. imager"class="main-logo" />



    </div>



    <!-- work-->
    <section class="page-section zigzag" >
        <div class="page-section-inner">
        <h1 class="heading">Project 2</h1>
            <div class="subheading"></div>
        </div>


<div id="project-gallery"><!-- swipper -->
<div class="gallery-container">
    <div class="swiper-container clearfix">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper clearfix">


        <!-- Images  -->

        <!-- ENDS images -->


        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<!-- ENDS swipper -->



        <div class="page-section-inner clearfix">

            <!-- project info -->
            <div class="project-info">
                                                    <p><strong>Date </strong><br/>مهرماه 93</p>

            </div>
            <!-- ENDS project info -->

            <div class="project-content"><p><a href="http://netsurf.ir/%d8%ae%d8%a7%d9%86%d9%87/attachment/03" rel="attachment wp-att-41"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-41" src="http://netsurf.ir/wp-content/uploads/03.jpg" alt="03" width="672" height="400" /></a> <a href="http://netsurf.ir/%d8%ae%d8%a7%d9%86%d9%87/attachment/04" rel="attachment wp-att-42"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-42" src="http://netsurf.ir/wp-content/uploads/04.jpg" alt="04" width="672" height="400" /></a></p>
</div>



        </div>

    </section>
    <!-- ENDS work-->







<!-- similar projects-->
<section class="page-section-white" >

    <div class="related-projects-holder">
        <div class="heading">Similar Projects</div>
        <ul class="related-projects clearfix">


            <li>


                <a href="http://netsurf.ir/work/project" class="thumb">     

<a href="http://netsurf.ir/work/project" class="thumb" >
    <img src="http://netsurf.ir/wp-content/uploads/04.jpg" alt="Project" />
</a>

</a>


                <a href="http://netsurf.ir/work/project" class="heading">Project</a>
            </li>


        </ul>
    </div>  
</section>
<!-- ENDS similar projects-->









<!-- social -->
<section class="page-section" >
    <!--  social icons -->
    <div class="icons ">
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            </div>
    <!-- ENDS social icons -->
</section >
<!-- ENDS social -->        <!-- WIDGETS -->
<section class="page-section" >
    <ul  class="widget-cols clearfix">
        <li class="first-col">
            <div class="widget-block"><h4 class="heading">جستجو</h4><form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="http://netsurf.ir/">
                <div>
                    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
                    <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
                    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
                </div>
            </form></div>       </li>

        <li class="second-col">
            <div class="widget-block"><h4 class="heading">نماد تجارتی</h4>          <div class="textwidget">1393 ©  Mr. imager </div>
        </div>      </li>

        <li class="third-col">
            <div class="widget-block"><h4 class="heading">برچسب ها</h4><div class="tagcloud"></div>
</div>      </li>

    </ul>
</section>
<!-- ENDS WIDGETS -->       
        <!-- footer -->
        <footer>
            <div class="inner">
                            </div>
        </footer>
        <!-- ENDSfooter -->


    </div>
    <!-- ENDS main content -->





<script type='text/javascript' src='http://netsurf.ir/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/jquery.form.min.js?ver=3.51.0-2014.06.20'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var _wpcf7 = {"loaderUrl":"http:\/\/netsurf.ir\/wp-content\/plugins\/contact-form-7\/images\/ajax-loader.gif","sending":"Sending ..."};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://netsurf.ir/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js?ver=4.0.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var myJsVars = {"inner_background":"http:\/\/netsurf.ir\/wp-content\/themes\/dokedoke\/img\/dummies\/page-bg.jpg","front_background1":"http:\/\/netsurf.ir\/wp-content\/themes\/dokedoke\/img\/slides\/02.jpg","front_background2":"http:\/\/netsurf.ir\/wp-content\/themes\/dokedoke\/img\/slides\/02.jpg","front_background_duration":"4000"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://netsurf.ir/wp-content/themes/dokedoke/js//custom.js?ver=4.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://netsurf.ir/wp-content/themes/dokedoke/js//superfish.js?ver=4.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://netsurf.ir/wp-content/themes/dokedoke/js//backstretch.js?ver=4.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://netsurf.ir/wp-content/themes/dokedoke/js//idangerous.swiper.js?ver=4.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://netsurf.ir/wp-content/themes/dokedoke/js//jquery.mixitup.min.js?ver=4.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://netsurf.ir/wp-content/themes/dokedoke/js//jquery.cycle2.js?ver=4.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://netsurf.ir/wp-includes/js/comment-reply.min.js?ver=4.0'></script>

</body>
</html>
```

this should be all on the project page,
when I add images to the project in wordpress panel it goes to the description so i think i need to have the theme to put the images into the slider but how?
and I copied pasted the live ones into the php and it applies to all the projects pages, it works thou